# design pattern for pluggable communications modules

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am designing my application to have several plugins that will provide different communication methods such as Bluetooth, TCP, UDP, XMPP, etc.

At the moment I have some of those communication methods included inside of the project. And I call one of those methods in a dirty way using simple switch cases.

Can you recommend me some design patterns I could apply here?

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enter [Strategy design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Basically you have a "context" class which needs to perform an action in different ways depending on the scenario.

Your create an abstract strategy ( or a Java  interface in this case ) defining the methods that concrete strategies should implement. You get your plugins to implement that interface, and in your first switch statement you create the correct concrete instance.

[image: strategy]

If you need to load them at runtime, you could use `Class.forName`

Answer (score 2):

The [strategy pattern](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Strategy_pattern) comes to mind.